# How can I change the committer of an old revision in SVN?

Tags: svn

I have a whole heap of legacy code that I checked into my SVN repository.  I checked it in under my user name.  I'd like to change the author of that commit to another user, 'legacy', in order to clean up the `svn blame` printouts.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to have have a pre-revprop-change hook in your repository hooks directory that will allow changes to the svn:author property.  (An executable script containing just "exit 0" will do.) Once you have this, then you can do:

```
svn propedit --revprop -rrev svn:author url
```

and make the necessary changes.

Comment: As an aside, it looks like you can use the svn:date magic property to set the commit date in a similar fashion. Whether that is a good idea, I leave up to you.

Comment: To get this to work, I had to use the --force option for svn. Also, vim likes to add new lines to the end of files, and I had to :set noendofline and :set binary to prevent that behavior. (Otherwise, every line from svn blame was two lines, due to an embedded newline in the author name.)

Comment: propset rather than propedit, and supplying the value in the command rather than throwing to an editor may help you out there Jason

Comment: For others trying this, be sure that you're svn text editor doesn't insert a newline after the author name. vim did this for me and it took quite a while to figure out why blame was busted.  

You can use propget to confirm that what is saved in the repo has no line break.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure you can do this directly but what is possible is dumping the repo, using `sed` on it and re-import that as a new repo.

Comment: Yeah, svn doesn't tend to allow for things like this directly (and on purpose).  Your method is likely the only way...